# Condition is not evaluated in loop

Tags: c++

The purpose of the conditional statement is to print out a simple text based menu and then store input from the user as well as evaluate this to the condition of a loop.

If the condition was not meet, the user should be prompted to enter in a int number, that would result in the condition being true. Instead it just exits the loop.

I have tried both while and now, if loops to accomplish the task.

Here is the Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

// Namespaces
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::istream;
using std::iostream;
using std::ostream;
using std::string;

// Variables
const string new_game = "Start a new game";
const string continue_game = "Continue your game";
const string load_save = "Load a save";

int menu_choice = 0;

const string choice_description = "You choice to";

// MAIN Program

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{

    cout << "Welcome to The Forgotten Time" <<endl;
    cout << "You have the following options" << endl;

    while (menu_choice < 1 || menu_choice > 3 )
        {

        cout << "1." << new_game << endl;
        cout << "2." << continue_game << endl;
        cout << "3." << load_save << endl;

        cin >> menu_choice;

        }

    switch (menu_choice)
    {
        case 1: cout << choice_description << new_game;
        case 2: cout << choice_description << continue_game;
        case 3: cout << choice_description << choice_description;

    }

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;

}
```

In the end i would like to be able to combine the conditional statement in a function
and pass it through a switch statement in order to create a sentence, that evaluates the
users input and displays their choice.

Comment: There is no loop in your code.

Comment: Not only `if (menu_choice < 1 || menu_choice > 4 )` isn't a loop, the condition looks pretty weird.

Comment: I must say, this an awesome community and I enjoy reading your suggestions a lot. It is the first time I have posted on Stackoverflow and I didn't even image that someone would take the time to answer my question, considering how many other questions are unanswered. :) Please let me know if I should improve on anything in regards to the Post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially you set:

```
int menu_choice = 0;
```

Then you ask:

```
if (menu_choice < 1 || menu_choice > 4 )
```

The choice is smaller than `1` so the `if block` is entered.
You then get some user input and exit the application.

Comment: Hi Loki. Thanks for your answer. I threw in a initial value of "0", in order to remove the random memory value from the variable. However I thought that with the return keyword it would re-evaluate the statement, which should then loop the process.

Comment: @Caspi: No. The return causes it to exit the current function. Since you are in main it just exits the application. To make a loop. Change `if` into `while` and remove the return.

Comment: Thank you Loki. That is some great info, I thought that the IF statement loop was like a function in the sense that it was limited to the scope of that IF statement and therefore would not be able to interfere with the Main function. Thank you very much for your answer. I will now look at how to provide the same functionality by using a switch.

Answer (score 0):

You have no loop in your code at all. Just an initial conditional statement that would return a true value because:

```
menu_choice=0;
```

and,

```
if(menu_choice<1 ||...)
```

You don't need a "return" statement, either. Put in a switch() after your if().
Also, you could just remove the second if() condition and put your whole main() content in a while() or do..while() loop.
Also, a switch is pretty efficient if you have a menu based display that takes in certain specific discrete-set of values.

Comment: Hi Ankit. How would I implement a switch instead of the IF statement? Also why do the IF statement not initiate a loop, after it reads the cin aswell as return, as it has changed the value from the initial "0" to "X"? Thanks for your suggestion on using a Switch instead. I tried using a switch instead like so: switch (menu_choice != 1, 2, 3)

Comment: If does not check the condition again, once it finishes the if(){} block. You could use goto's to go back and check again, but all people i know discourage goto's as it is highly inefficient, and increases complexity. You might wanna read up on if() and for()/while() loop. try the IBM site. Or, the internet will have sufficient resources. If is a conditional terminating block.

Comment: Also, read up on switch too, your syntax is messed up.
switch(menu_choice) {
case 1: ....; break;
case 2: .....; break;
default: print("Messed UP Input");}

Answer (score 0):

Remove your if condition, instead use a do while loop.

```
do{
cout << "1." << new_game << endl; 
cout << "2." << continue_game << endl;
cout << "3." << load_save << endl;
cin >> menu_choice;
} 
while (menu_choice!=0);
```

Comment: Hi Dualdark. This would normally seem like the solution, however I want the statement to run as long as the User haven't pressed either 1,2 or 3. In the case of the above code, this would validate any number pressed other than "0". I appreciate your contribution none the less. I couldn't figure out the syntax for the do while loop, but with the above example you have told me it. :)

Comment: Please share your final code, I didn't understand what's what you need.

Comment: I have updated with the most recent code and it works as intended.